# Using search method from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to count the number of times certain words appear in the strings.  Every time I run it I get a

> uncaught TypeErro: undefined is not a function

I just actually need to count the number of times each "major" appears.

Below is my code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sortedarray.length; i++)
    {
        if(sortedarray.search("Multimedia") === true)
        {
            multimedia += 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(multimedia);
```

Here is my csv file which is stored in a 1d array.

```
"NAME","MAJOR","CLASS STANDING","ENROLLMENT STATUS"
"Smith, John A","Computer Science","Senior","E"
"Johnson, Brenda B","Computer Science","Senior","E"
"Green, Daisy L","Information Technology","Senior","E"
"Wilson, Don A","Information Technology","Junior","W"
"Brown, Jack J","Multimedia","Senior","E"
"Schultz, Doug A","Network Administration","Junior","E"
"Webber, Justin","Business Administration","Senior","E"
"Alexander, Debbie B","Multimedia","Senior","E"
"St. John, Susan G","Information Technology","Junior","D"
"Finklestein, Harold W","Multimedia","Freshman","E"
```

Comment: If anyone needs more code I can edit it and put some more in.  I'm just trying to keep it simple.

Comment: There is no such thing as `Array.search`.

Comment: The error you're getting effectively says `Array.prototype.search is undefined`. You'll have to find another way to do your search.

Comment: search is not a inbuilt function provided by Array in javascript. do you have your own implementation of it?

Answer (score 2):

What you're probably trying to do is:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sortedarray.length; i++)
{
    if(sortedarray[i].indexOf("Multimedia") !== -1)
    {
        multimedia++;
    }
}
console.log(multimedia);
```

I use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexof) since [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) is a bit of overkill if you're not using regexes.

Also, I replaced the `+= 1` with `++`. It's practically the same.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain what's wrong? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to search inside each string not the array. To only search inside the "Major" column, you can start your loop at index 1 and increment by 4 :

```
var multimedia = 0;
for(var i = 1; i < sortedarray.length; i += 4)
{
    if(sortedarray[i].indexOf("Multimedia") > -1)
    {
        multimedia += 1;
    }
}
console.log(multimedia);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more straightforward solution. First you count all the words using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), then you can access them with dot notation (or bracket notation if you have a string or dynamic value):

```
var words = ["NAME","MAJOR","CLASS STANDING","ENROLLMENT STATUS"...]

var count = function(xs) {
  return xs.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    // If a word already appeared, increment count by one
    // otherwise initialize count to one
    acc[x] = ++acc[x] || 1
    return acc
  },{}) // an object to accumulate the results
}

var counted = count(words)

// dot notation
counted.Multimedia //=> 3

// bracket notation
counted['Information Technology'] //=> 3
```

Comment: Way too over-complicated for someone that's obviously learning to program.

Comment: So this stuff is over-complicated nowadays? I guess we're back to `for` loops, oh my.

Comment: There are a number of semi advanced concepts here, ++ on an undefined variable, boolean operations that don't return booleans, reduce functions. Still a good solution, a beginner can learn from it. It's not overly complicated, but I would not call it straight forward. Not a reason to be downvoted though.

Comment: You're using `reduce`, pre-increments, and that `|| 1`. Those are functionalities / concepts that aren't handled in any beginner JS course. Beginners can only learn from this if you tell them where to find the relevant documentation, of provide a step-by-step explanation of the code.

Comment: @Cerbrus They can still learn if they do a little searching, which if they really want to learn, they will. Some inline documentation wouldn't hurt though

Comment: That's what I'm talking about :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly that you need this or not. But I think its better to count each word occurrences in single loop like this:

```
var occurencesOfWords = {};

for(var i = 0; i < sortedarray.length; i++)
{
    var noOfOccurences = (occurencesOfWords[sortedarray[i]]==undefined? 
                          1 : ++occurencesOfWords[sortedarray[i]]);

    occurencesOfWords[sortedarray[i]] = noOfOccurences; 
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(occurencesOfWords));
```

So you'll get something like this in the end:

```
{"Multimedia":3,"XYZ":2}
```

Answer (score -1):

`.search` is `undefined` and isn't a `function` on the array.

But exists on the current `string` you want to check ! Just select the current `string` in the array with `sortedarray[i]`.

Fix your code like that:

```
for(var i = 0; i < sortedarray.length; i++)
{
    if(sortedarray[i].search("Multimedia") === true)
    {
        multimedia += 1;
    }
}
console.log(multimedia);
```

Comment: So this should search through the array's element and find the word I'm looking for? Thank you.

Comment: ` === true` is not what you want. Have a look at the return values from [`String.prototype.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) (It's similar to `indexOf`)